# finding the approximate course change

Tags: navigation

I'm studying for my nav test (EASA ppl) I will be thankful for a good explanation solving this
:

```
The distance from 'A' to 'B' measures 120 NM. At a distance of 55 NM from 'A' the pilot realizes a
deviation of 7 NM to the right. What approximate course change must be made to reach 'B' directly?
a) 15° left
b) 8° left
c) 6° left
d) 14° left
```

Comment: Have you come across the "1 in 60" rule in your studies? That should help you solve this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires using the 1 in 60 rule.

This rule states that if you have flown 60 miles and become 1 mile off track, your track error is 1 degree.

The rule is based on the small-angle approximation (which states that, for small angles, sin θ ≈ θ, where θ is in radians), along with the fact that one radian (which is about 57.3°) is close to 60°. In reality, a 1 mile in 60 error is 0.96°, and the rule becomes increasingly inaccurate for larger errors. It states that for each degree off (or displacement) over a distance of 60 nautical miles (NM) will result in 1 NM off course. Plug this in for this question too.

Comment: thanks guys ! I now understand the principle of it